# Certbot error: check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Tags: dns, certbot, namecheap

I have added the following host records to my namecheap domain, but the certbot still can't verify the SSL certificate, it keeps giving the error: 'DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for [www.example.co.uk](http://www.example.co.uk) - check that a DNS record exists for this domain'[image]

I don't know if my host records are wrong, I know the top one isn't but the 2nd one might be?

Comment: For `Host` you have specified `www.example.com`. If you specify the entire domain name, it must end with a dot (period), otherwise, just enter `www`. The way you entered it the full resource record name is `www.example.com.example.com`. Adding the dot to the end of the domain name makes it an absolute fully-qualified domain name. Without the trailing dot the name is a child name of the domain.

Comment: You just need to have an A record with "www".  @john-hanley are you referring to the zone file which of course will look more like what you're describing?

Comment: @Chiwda - I am not referring to the zone file (but that applies there also). I am referring to the GUI user interface as shown in the question screenshot. Each domain registration / DNS server has its own interface. In the case of Namecheap, if you enter www.example.com as a resource record for the domain example.com the two entries are concatenated if the resource record does not end with a dot.

Comment: So then just using "www" should do the trick since it will concatenate it to the domain example.com?

Comment: @Chiwda - that is correct, just use www